# get a response from httpclient postasync in wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpclient

i have the following code that uploads a photo to a web service , i need to get the response from the service , and i'm using httpclient class here's my code

```
var fileUploadUrl = Globals.baseUrl + "/laravelProjects/VisWall/public/test";
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    photoStream.Position = 0;
                    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                   content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "image", "koko");
                    await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content).ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });
                }
```

Comment: i've just found the answer you shoud read string async from the results content       string ss =await postTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 0):

i've just found the answer you shoud read string async from the results content

```
string stringResponse =await postTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```